# Does a job inside Github Action already have access to its repo contents?

Tags: github-actions

I wanted to zip my entire repo using Github Action Workflow. So my question is, does the repository already available inside a job? Or do I need to install git and clone the repository to a location on the runner/container?

Answer (score 3):

You can checkout the repository with the [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) action. This will make your repository available for subsequent steps in the job.

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
```